# Slack API requests to an endpoint which requires SSO

Tags: slack, slack-api, shibboleth

I want to create a Slack bot which will monitor incoming messages of channel, and respond to those messages based on the content using Events and Web API.

In Events API, the verification URL which I am currently using requires Shibboleth login i.e I need to put in username and password if I want to access that URL through browser.

How do I have Slack send its request to that URL? Currently Slack gets HTTP 500 error from the server, and also my server doesn't get any hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Slack help chat, I was told that Slack can't do auth. I was suggested to use proxy of some kind, but I ended up removing the Shibboleth from my server. Slack does sign every request it sends, so to have server respond to attackers, verify each request is from Slack before responding.